# how to display tweets of particular time period using twitter api

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, twitter

my requirement is to display tweets of particular time period using twitter api. I am using getsearch method of api to get all tweets i have tried the following code to display tweets of particular time period.

```
Three_days_ago = datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.created_at > Three_days_ago:
        print tweet
```

but i am getting error `'can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode'`
How to do this please suggest me..

Comment: `tweet.created_at` is not a `datetime`, it's text

Comment: post the `tweet.create_at`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tweet.created_at looks like Mon, 29 Apr 2013 01:12:50 +0000 how can i convert my tweet.create_at to datetime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

```
from dateutil import parser


Three_days_ago = datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
for tweet in tweets:
    tweeted_datetime = parser.parse(tweet.created_at)
    if tweeted_datetime > Three_days_ago:
        print tweet, tweeted_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p")
```

I'm not sure that you'll be able to get the milliseconds as it's not passed while parsing. For more `strftime` options refer [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the reply is there any way to convert date of this format "Mon, 29 Apr 2013 01:12:50 +0000" to "2013-04-29 01:12:50.784572" Please suggest me.

Comment: Thanks for the code its working but we are getting output in single quote ('2013-04-29 01:12:50 AM'), but my requirement is to compare this with 2013-04-29 01:12:50 AM (without quotes). so how to get the date without quotes.

Comment: When it comes with quotes it's string. And when it comes with `u''` it's unicode. I'm pretty sure that your `2013-04-29 01:12:50 AM` will be either a string or unicode. So the comparison should work.

Comment: the output of this line datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(days = 3) is in datetime.datetime format, so when i compare this with  ('2013-04-29 01:12:50 AM') it is giving error as cannot compare datetime.datetime to str.

Answer (score 0):

As @jamylak says, tweet.created_at is text not a datetime.

You can convert it to a datetime according to the rules given here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior